# Type of ANOVA to use: Split-Plot, Nested … or others? Water quality project

Tags: time-series, anova, mixed-model, nested-data, split-plot

I was wondering if I could get some help in determining the correct ANOVA analysis to run on a water quality project in am working on. 
My dataset have the following variables:

- Habitat Type (fixed) (3 types; connected bays, disconnected bays, the Main Lake)
- Location (fixed) (10 total; 4 connected bays, 3 disconnected bays, 3 main Lake)
- Sampling site (fixed) (4 in each location- 40 total)
- Season (samples were collected in the spring, summer, and fall – 3 time total)
- Year (samples were collected for 2 consecutive years)

My goal is to see if 1) Habitat Type, 2) Season, 3) Year, 4) interaction of Habitat Type*Season, and 5) interaction of Habitat Type*Year have an impact on various water quality parameters.

A colleague of mine suggested a split plot design to account for possible differences between locations and the repeated sampling in each location (4 sampling sites in each location), but is this feasible with the repeated sampling in during each season and year?

I have also been looking into nested designs, but I also unclear if this would work in the situation.

If anyone has any suggestions on the correct analysis to run in this situation, and perhaps SAS or R code as well, I would be greatly appreciate it!